# How to change keyboard shortcut for 'underline' in Word 2007

Tags: ms-word

I wanted to change the keyboard shortcut for the 'underline' command, but it does not appear in the "Adjust keyboard" menu in the "Start tab" category (in the customize menu).

Does anyone know how to find the corresponding entry or could provide a way to change it in a different way, e.g. programatically?

Thanks!
Christian

Answer (score 2):

In Word-Options go to "Customize Ribbon" => Keyboard Shortcuts => In the categories look for "all commands" (nearly at the bottom above the separator line), then it should be somewhere in the right list box.